# In Google Sheets, can the cell color change once a specific collaborator makes a change?

Tags: google-sheets, background-color, user-defined-functions

I have three users working on a spreadsheet in Google Sheets, two of which are on tablets, and I'm curious if I can make it so when one of us makes a change to a cell, the cell would change to a specific color.  Each of us would have a color assigned to us.  This way, you would quickly be able to see who last edited what.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The tablets don't allow users to view the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

If each user logs in with their own gmail account, you might try to use: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user